# Laravel Errors in tinker using factory->create() but not when running migration/seed commands in artisan

Tags: php, laravel

I am able to successfully run the migration/factory/seeders from the command line using `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`

However when I try to manually create a category using tinker, I'm getting errors:

```
<warning>PHP Warning:  Array to string conversion in /Users/[my_name]/Sites/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php on line 99</warning>
TypeError: Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, string given, called in /Users/[my_name]/Sites/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 886
```

And

```
<warning>PHP Warning:  Array to string conversion in /Users/[my_name]/Sites/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php on line 99</warning>
=> App\Models\Category {#4529
     name: [
       "quaerat",
       "voluptatem",
     ],
     slug: "array",
   }
```

Factory code:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class CategoryFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $name = $this->faker->words(2,true);
        $slug = Str::of($name)->slug('-');

        return [
            'name' => ucwords($name),
            'slug' => $slug
        ];
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Why do the two methods (make and create) cause different, albeit related, errors?
2. Why does tinker get tripped up when the normal migration/seed process works fine?

Please and thank you.

Comment: why is 'name' an array of strings?

Comment: The second argument to `$this->faker->words()` should ensure it returns a string. This code doesn't match up with the error message you're getting.

Comment: Also, the error message should include a stack trace so you can find out what line and file of *your* code is causing the problem. Posting an error message pointing to one of Laravel's files doesn't tell us much.

Comment: @miken32 in tinker, that's the full extent of the error message. There is no corresponding message in the application/browser.

Comment: @miken32 — I agree the error doesn't match, and it's inconsistent because artisan doesn't throw any errors, hence my posting here. I'm wondering if there's some "reset" process for tinker I'm supposed to do after I change the factory?

Comment: Factories aren’t cached AFAIK, but you can try. `artisan cache:clear`. Check `storage/logs/laravel.log` for a stack trace.

Comment: You should restart the tinker process whenever you update your application code.

Comment: @Rwd this was it! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why the two errors were different, but it's pedantic.

Thank you to @Rwd! I now know that we need to restart tinker after we change our application code in Laravel.

The string to array error was from a previous version of the code before I figured out to add the second parameter to `$this->faker->words()` — which is why it worked with `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` and with in `php artisan tinker \App\Models\Category::factory()->create();`